Audio routingForm in vb net
I am building a professional audio mixer in C# VB.NET in Windows Visual Studio 2022.
Naudio Library is used.
One thing I have to build is a routing page for the devices to route between the (mixerchannels, sends directouts funtions etc), and the asio devices for the inputs and outputs.
Is there anyone who can help me to direct me in the right way to build that up and how?
My goal is to have a form with all the sources on the top of the form  and destinations on the site  of the form like in maybe two panels.
And I want to make a route using a grid with for example radio button or an normal button or that kind of function.
What is the best way to start and what do I use for function that automatic imports the channels.
Do I really have to build that up with rows and columns or with a datagripvieuw or is there a better way.
I also need to make this in categories like inputs / outputs /sends / busses, that are separate audio routes from one channel.
So every category has it unique sources or destinations.
I have searched on the web and Youtube but there is not a good example about this kind of thing to start.
Hope anyone is so kind to give me some direction.
Thanks very much
Kind regards,
Harm

Hi, welcome. Please read how to ask. This is a too general request
